# How to define eloquent relationship without using model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following the official documentation it is very easy to define a relationship between two models. However, One of my models just need to access data from 4 different table in a one to one basis. Those tables will have no functionality. So, I don't want to build a model for them.

For example I can do this,

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

Here to complete this relationship successfully I need to have a Phone model. However, if I don't have a model can I use just the table name to define relationship? I want to use something like,  `return $this->hasOne(DB::table('phones');`.

I reckon, if I can somehow use this I will have less models to work with which will make my code more manageable. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Well you can use join if you don't want to have model. Is it a good practice? Yes I think so, originally that's how it works the model in laravel with relationship just help us to do it in simple way.

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about join. I will use that.

Comment: You're welcome :)